# How to parse String date to date object in ios swift?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am parsing date from server into a custom format :-
This is the date :- "8/9/2017 3:58:00 AM" but it is not parsing into Date object using this format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" because obviously the month, day and hour is single digit

As per my knowledge it should parse automatically because Android's DateFormat parses the same date.
This is the code snippet i am using :-

```
func getDateString(_ dateString:String) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

This function is returning null

Comment: are you sure? I tried your code in playground and it seems to work [Attachment with result](https://i.gyazo.com/90bf726098f946898a8fbd9dc500b00f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, although you should also add some error-checking.

Try this (it will run in a Playground):

```
// returns an empty string "" if the date format is invalid
func getDateString(_ dateString:String) -> String {

    var strResult = ""

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"

    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        strResult = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

    return strResult

}

let dateString = getDateString("8/9/2017 3:58:00 AM")

print(dateString)   // prints "09 Aug 2017"
```

If you change your "source" string to an invalid date/time - such as changing the month from `8 to 18` or the hour from `3 to 13` - you will see the returned value is an empty string.